# Substitution Lemma (Enderton)

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

I am reading Enderton's book, *A mathematical introduction to logic*, and I have a problem with the following lemma.

> (**Substitution Lemma**, *page 134*) If the term $t$ is substitutable for the variable $x$ in the wff $\phi$ then $$\vDash_\mathfrak{A} \phi^x_t[s] \text{ iff } \vDash_\mathfrak{A} \phi[s(x|\overline s(t))].$$

He proceeds by induction on $\phi$, I only write the case where I have a trouble to understand it:

> *Case 4:* $\phi = \forall y \psi$, and x does occur free in $\psi$. Because $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$, we know that: (by the definition of "substitutable")
>
> 1. $y$ does not occur in $t$, and
> 2. $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\psi$.
>
> By the $1.$ we have, $$\overline s(t) = \overline {s(y|d)}(t) \hspace{2cm}(*)$$ for any $d \in \mathfrak{|A|}$ . Since $x \neq y$, $\phi^x_t = \forall y \psi^x_t$.
>
> $\vDash_\mathfrak{A} \phi^x_t[s]$ iff for every $d$, $\vDash_\mathfrak{A} \psi^x_t[s(y|d)]$, 
>   iff for every $d$, $\vDash_\mathfrak{A} \psi[s(y|d)(x|\overline s(t))]$ by the inductive hypothesis and $(*)$, iff $\phi[s(x|\overline s(t))]$.

I do not see why we need to use the fact $(*)$ in the second iff. I think that follows directly from inductive hypothesis.

Comment: What do you think the inductive hypothesis states in this particular case?

Comment: @DerekElkins If the term $t$ is substitutable for the variable $x$ in the wff $\psi$ then as inductive hypothesis we assume that for $\psi$, $$\vDash_\mathfrak{A} \psi^x_t[s] \text{ iff } \vDash_\mathfrak{A} \psi[s(x|\overline s(t))].$$ Since we know that $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\psi$ we can apply the inductive hypothesis with $s(y|d)$. Oh, I see. I apply inductive hypothesis for $s(y|d)$, but do not modify $\overline s(t)$ that is in the case must be $\overline{s(y|d)}(t)$ and here we use the fact $(*)$.